# Not hitting controller method using nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes, erb

I created an Open House for a specific listing. I am now trying to add an RSVP function. I keep getting an error and I can't figure it out. I'm sure it's something stupid, but I'm just not seeing it.

Rake Routes:

```
rsvp_listing_open_house GET  /listings/:listing_id/open_houses/:id/rsvp(.:format)  open_houses#rsvp
```

My Routes:

```
resources :listings do
  member do
    get 'like'
    get 'unlike'
    get 'duplicate'
    get 'gallery'
    delete 'gallery' => 'listings#clear_gallery'
    get 'manage_photos'
    get 'craigslist'
    get "add_to_collection"
    get 'request_photos'
  end
  resources :open_houses do
    member do
      get 'rsvp'
    end
  end
  resources :listing_feedbacks do
    member do
      get 'archive_feedback'
    end
  end
end
```

My Controller:

```
def rsvp
  @open_house_rsvp = params[:open_house_rsvp]
  agent_id = params[:agent_id]
  open_house_id = params[:open_house_id]
  OpenHouseRsvp.create(:agent_id => agent_id, :open_house_id => open_house_id )
  flash[:notice] = "Your RSVP has been submitted!"
  redirect_to listing_open_houses_path
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to "RSVP", rsvp_listing_open_house_path %>
```

Errors:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in OpenHouses#index

No route matches {:action=>"rsvp", :controller=>"open_houses", :listing_id=>"5341"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting?

Comment: It looks like you're not passing in an id or object to the path helper as an argument, therefore it doesn't know exactly which `:id` to use for the route.

Comment: Posted the errors. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error provided, the path helper is already receiving a `:listing_id`, and is expecting an `:id` from an open house object, so that it can properly construct the path. Assuming you've got an `@open_house` object defined in your controller, your path helper should look like this:

```
<%= link_to "RSVP", rsvp_listing_open_house_path @open_house %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The root needs two objects, `listing` and `house`.

Comment: When I add @open_house, I get a new error.

    No route matches {:action=>"rsvp", :controller=>"open_houses", :id=>nil, :listing_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :listing_id]

Comment: @NicNilov The listing_id in this particular case is inferred from the page the link is being rendered on, according to the exception provided.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to post comment so just summary the comments from Zoran and Nic above:

- `rsvp_listing_open_house_path` requires 2 params: **listing_id**, **open_house_id**, you can use `rsvp_listing_open_house_path(@listing, @open_house)` or `rsvp_listing_open_house_path(@listing.id, @open_house.id)`
- Make sure you have **@listing** and **@open_house** available in your controller action (you may name them differently). Otherwise, you will get the error mentioned in your comment: `No route matches {:action=>"rsvp", :controller=>"open_houses", :id=>nil, :listing_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :listing_id]`

Comment: So I have an open_house_rsvps table that the RSVP is supposed to populate. In that table there is open_house_id and agent_id. Why do I need to pass in the listing id?